# Getting null while fetching data in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, fetch-api

I want to fetch a details of the one student I wrote the method for that . It working with postman but not working when i connect it with frontend

frontend controller for fetching student details

```js
export const getStudent = (studentId, token) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/student/${studentId}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

setting the values

```js
const [student, setStudent] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    admissionNumber: "",
    rollNumber: "",
    age: "",
    gender: "",
    faculty: "",
    email: "",
  });

  const preload = (studentId) => {
    getStudent(user._id, token, studentId).then((student) => {
      if (student?.error) {
        setStudent(console.log(student.error));
      } else {
        setStudent(student);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    preload();
  }, []);
```

**backend**

```
exports.getStudent = (req, res) => {
  return res.json(req.student);
};
```

fetching status is ok but response is null
[image]

[image]

Comment: Something is not adding up here. You define `getStudent` expecting two parameters, `studentId` and `token`. You then define `preload` expecting a single parameter, `studentId`. In `useEffect` you then call `preload` without providing any parameters (`studentId` will be `undefined`). Within `preload` you then call `getStudent` with 3 parameters (it only expects 2). The first parameter you pass is a user id, while the function expects a student id. The second parameter looks correct. I'm not sure what is going on here, but I suggest first fixing your parameters.

Comment: That works.... Thank you so much for answer. You got it right way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Code**

```
 const preload = (studentId) => {
getStudent(studentId, token).then((data) => {
  if (data.error) {
    setStudent(console.log(data.error));
  } else {
    setStudent(student);
  }
});
```

};

preload needs only two parameters userid and token

**In useEffect it needs to pass the studentId to get the details**

```
 useEffect(() => {
preload(match.params.studentId);
  }, []);
```